# NSString: Return value or Empty string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've been looking at a several Google search results and have found various ways to test an `NSString` for `nil`, etc.

So I decided to write some `category` methods for `NSString` to help. However it's not working as expected and am wondering if someone can help me figure out why and possible help with a solution.

So here is what I came up with:

`NSString+Extenstions.h`

```
#import 

@interface NSString (Extensions)

- (NSString *)stringOrNil;
- (NSString *)stringOrEmpty;

@end
```

`NSString+Extenstions.m`

```
#import "NSString+Extensions.h"

@implementation NSString (Extensions)

- (NSString *)stringOrNil {
    return self == nil || [self length] == 0 ? nil : self;
}

- (NSString *)stringOrEmpty {
    return [self stringOrNil] == nil ? @"" : self;
}

@end
```

So the idea behind `stringOrEmpty` is to force the result as an empty `NSString` (not `nil`) if the object is `nil` or the length is 0.

Testing:

```
NSString *name = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", [name stringOrEmpty]); // result: (null)
```

I expected, the result above to be a blank, but the console logged it as `(null)`. S I changed the `stringOrEmpty` method to `return [[self stringOrNil] length] == 0 ? @"yes" : @"no";` and expected to see `yes`, but again got `(null)`. It seems like `stringOrEmpty` is not being called.

Lastly I tested the following: `NSLog(@"%@", [name class]);` and again the result was `(null)`.

Am I misunderstanding something? How can I write a category that will return a blank `NSString` value if the value is `nil` or truly empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Sending message to `nil` object does not get called. It simply returns nil. You need to define them as class methods.

Comment: @ozgur ah, so even though I am defining `name` as a `NSString`, giving it `nil` dies not allow a call to the `NSString` methods?

Comment: A message to nil does nothing and returns `nil, Nil, NULL, 0, or 0.0` depending on the type. So yeah, your are right.

Comment: `nil` isn't an instance of `NSString` or any object, so you can't deal with `nil` using instance methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil` isn't an instance of `NSString` or any object, so you can't deal with `nil` using instance methods.

A message to `nil` does nothing, it doesn't even get called. It just simply returns `nil`. You need to define them as class methods:

```
@interface NSString (Extensions)

+ (NSString *)stringOrNil:(NSString *)string;
+ (NSString *)stringOrEmpty:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

--

```
@implementation NSString (Extensions)

+ (NSString *)stringOrNil:(NSString *)string {
  return string.length ? string : nil;
}

+ (NSString *)stringOrEmpty:(NSString *)string {
  return string ? string : @"";
}

@end
```

Here is how you can call them:

```
NSString *name = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringOrEmpty:name]); // result: ("")
```

Comment: The `stringOrNil` method has a needless check. Just do `return string.length ? string : nil;`. And `stringOrEmpty` should be `return string ? string : @"";`.